AttributeError: "The layer sequential_2 has never been called" when trying to generate Grad-CAM heatmap from a trained ResNet50 model
I'm working on generating a Grad-CAM heatmap from a trained ResNet50 model, but I've been encountering a persistent error related to sequential_2. Despite feeding the model with input images, I keep getting an AttributeError saying that sequential_2 has never been called. I'm hoping to get help resolving this issue.
I have trained a ResNet50 model for skin lesion classification using Keras, and saved it as ResNet50_skin_lesion_final_v2.keras. The model structure includes a resnet50 base, followed by global average pooling, a dense layer, dropout, and a final output dense layer with 8 classes. I want to generate a Grad-CAM heatmap using the conv5_block3_out layer of ResNet50 to visualize where the model is focusing on an input image.
When I try to create the Grad-CAM heatmap, I get the following error:
AttributeError: The layer sequential_2 has never been called and thus has no defined input.
First, I confirmed that the model layer exists
resnet50 <KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 2048), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_21197>
global_average_pooling2d_3 <KerasTensor shape=(None, 2048), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_21200>
dense_5 <KerasTensor shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_21203>
dropout_2 <KerasTensor shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_21207>
dense_6 <KerasTensor shape=(None, 8), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_21212>
The code for generating the Grad-CAM heatmap is here
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
# Load trained model (ResNet50_skin_lesion_final_v2)
model = load_model('ResNet50_skin_lesion_final_v2.keras')

# Function to preprocess the input image
def preprocess_input_image(img_path, target_size=(224, 224)):
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=target_size)
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    img_array /= 255.0  # Rescale the image like the training data
    return img_array

# Function to generate Grad-CAM heatmap
def generate_gradcam_heatmap(model, img_array, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # Forward pass to ensure the model input is called
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    if pred_index is None:
        pred_index = tf.argmax(predictions[0])

    # Get the ResNet50 base model
    base_model = model.get_layer('resnet50')

    # Build a model that outputs the activations of the last conv layer and the model     output
    grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        inputs=model.input, 
        outputs=[base_model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Watch the gradients for the convolutional layer
        conv_outputs, predictions = grad_model(img_array)
        class_output = predictions[:, pred_index]

    # Compute the gradient of the class output with respect to the feature map
    grads = tape.gradient(class_output, conv_outputs)

    # Take the mean of the gradients across the channels
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # Multiply the output feature map by the pooled gradients
    conv_outputs = conv_outputs[0]
    conv_outputs *= pooled_grads

    # Generate the heatmap
    heatmap = tf.reduce_mean(conv_outputs, axis=-1)
    heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) / np.max(heatmap)  # Normalize between 0 and 1
    return heatmap.numpy()

# Function to display the Grad-CAM heatmap on top of the original image
def display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap, alpha=0.4):
    # Load the original image
    img = image.load_img(img_path)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)

    # Resize the heatmap to match the original image size
    heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)
    heatmap = np.expand_dims(heatmap, axis=-1)
    heatmap = tf.image.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1])).numpy()

    # Create an RGB heatmap
    heatmap = np.uint8(plt.cm.jet(heatmap[..., 0]) * 255)

    # Superimpose the heatmap on the original image
    superimposed_img = heatmap * alpha + img

    # Display the image
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.imshow(superimposed_img.astype('uint8'))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

# Example usage
img_path =          '/mnt/c/Users/arjay/Downloads/Ubuntu/ISIC_2019_Skin_Lesion_Data/ISIC_2019_Training_Input/m    anual_test/ISIC_0027665.jpg'
img_array = preprocess_input_image(img_path)

# Generate the Grad-CAM heatmap from the last conv layer of ResNet50
heatmap = generate_gradcam_heatmap(model, img_array,      last_conv_layer_name='conv5_block3_out')

# Display the Grad-CAM heatmap on the original image
display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap)

The error would be like this
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[128], line 82
79 img_array = preprocess_input_image(img_path)
81 # Generate the Grad-CAM heatmap from the last conv layer of ResNet50
---> 82 heatmap = generate_gradcam_heatmap(model, img_array, last_conv_layer_name='conv5_block3_out')
84 # Display the Grad-CAM heatmap on the original image
85 display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap)
Cell In[128], line 30
26 base_model = model.get_layer('resnet50')
28 # Build a model that outputs the activations of the last conv layer and the model output
29 grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
---> 30     inputs=model.input,
31     outputs=[base_model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
32 )
34 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
35     # Watch the gradients for the convolutional layer
36     conv_outputs, predictions = grad_model(img_array)
File ~/projects/tf217/tf217/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py:254, in Operation.input(self)
244 @property
245 def input(self):
246     """Retrieves the input tensor(s) of a symbolic operation.
247
...
292         f"{node_index}, but the operation has only "
293         f"{len(self._inbound_nodes)} inbound nodes."
294     )
AttributeError: The layer sequential_2 has never been called and thus has no defined input.
My questions are

Why does the error mention sequential_2 even though I'm loading and referring to the trained ResNet50 model?
How can I properly feed the model with input data so that I can generate the Grad-CAM heatmap?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
